# Ideal territory for Bone Chip dealers?

Tags: everquest

After killing too many skeletons on the Project 1999 server I have 3 bags of bone chips I would like to sell to players. I have been attempting to sell these in East Commonlands Tunnel where everyone else goes to sell. However, no one is buying any of them, despite my prices being half to a third of what I've seen other people advertising.

I think my problem is that bone chips are only useful for necromancers and a small number of turn-in quests, and these players don't walk through East Commonlands very often. I think I can get better value by traveling to a location where I'm more likely to find a customer, such as a zone where mid to high level necromancers congregate.

The problem is I really don't know where those zones are, I'm not familiar with necromancers and it's been 10+ years since I've played the game much. Do you have suggestions where I should go? I should point out I'm ogre shaman, so I can't get into certain cities and can't teleport, but I have SOW and a great deal of patience so if I can walk/boat there I can probably get there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key when selling bone chips, is to offer convenience. Since necros are typically soloing (esp. on p99), they more likely to be in outdoor zones that offer decent solo exp.

The following zones come to mind:

- Rathe Mountains
- Estate of Unrest
- Lake of Ill Omen
- The Overthere
- Dreadlands

This is by no means a complete list.

Also, there's a quest for low level Iksar in Field of Bone that offers a good faction boost in Cabilis. In the event a non-Iksar wanted to complete one of the Cabilis quest lines, they may be in the market to buy bone chips. This I know from experience. I completed the shackle quests as a human monk.

Source: 5 years on live, casual on p99, community member of EQClassic.org.

Comment: I asked this question several levels ago, and have had good luck selling in Field of Bone and Kurns Tower, mostly to people who were looking for sellers. East commons has not been very useful. Bone chips are a good byproduct of camping for the iksar berzerker club in Kurns.

Comment: Sorry to "necro" your question (lol), but I was hoping for some rep to participate more on this site, and classic EQ happens to be an area of expertise.